# AWK and Grep instructions

Tags: awk, grep

below is a file and I have to search with awk or grep if the numbers from usernames are odd and if the first character from name is vowel.

`aaie1001:x:1:600:Alex:/home/scs/gr911/aaie1001:/bin/bash
abie1032:x:2:600:Mihai:/home/scs/gr911/abie1032:/bin/bash
acie1203:x:3:600:Andra:/home/scs/gr911/acie1203:/bin/bash`

acie1203, abie1032, aaie1001 are the usernames and Alex, Mihai,  Andra are the names.

I tried to do something like this:
`awk -F'[^0-9]*' '$0=$2'` to get the numbers from username but I don't know how can I print the username if the number is odd.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!
same idea but can be written more compactly as

```
$ awk '/^[aouei][^:]*[13579]:/' file

aaie1001:x:1:600:Alex:/home/scs/gr911/aaie1001:/bin/bash
acie1203:x:3:600:Andra:/home/scs/gr911/acie1203:/bin/bash
```

if you want the negation of this (not clear to me which you asked for), simply negate the pattern

```
$ awk '!/^[aouei][^:]*[13579]:/' file

abie1032:x:2:600:Mihai:/home/scs/gr911/abie1032:/bin/bash
```

If, instead of the username you want the restriction on Name instead, it will easier to split the fields

```
$ awk -F: '$1 ~ /[13579]$/ && tolower($5)~/^[aeoui]/' file

aaie1001:x:1:600:Alex:/home/scs/gr911/aaie1001:/bin/bash
acie1203:x:3:600:Andra:/home/scs/gr911/acie1203:/bin/bash
```

again, for the negation.

```
$ awk -F: '!($1 ~ /[13579]$/ && tolower($5)~/^[aeoui]/)' file

abie1032:x:2:600:Mihai:/home/scs/gr911/abie1032:/bin/bash
```

Comment: right, I missed the Name distinction. I thought usernames are given with some convention and checking for it.  Now updated but yours were first.  If you fix yours OP can change the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat f
aaie1001:x:1:600:Alex:/home/scs/gr911/aaie1001:/bin/bash
abie1032:x:2:600:Mihai:/home/scs/gr911/abie1032:/bin/bash
acie1203:x:3:600:Andra:/home/scs/gr911/acie1203:/bin/bash
acie1208:x:3:600:Andra:/home/scs/gr911/acie1203:/bin/bash

$ grep -P '^[a-z]+[0-9]*[02468]:(?:[^:]*):(?:[^:]*):(?:[^:]*):[AEIOUaeiou].*$' f
acie1208:x:3:600:Andra:/home/scs/gr911/acie1203:/bin/bash
$
```

using `perl` syntax to grep required records, `(?:regex)` are non capturing groups and `[02468]` ensures number(s) in field 1 are even and `:[AEIOUaeiou]` implies vowels right after `:` i.e as 1st char in Name field

Another shorter version can be something like this to group unnecessary fields:

```
$ grep -P '^[a-z]+[0-9]*[02468]:(?:[^:]*:){3}[AEIOUaeiou].*$' f
acie1208:x:3:600:Andra:/home/scs/gr911/acie1203:/bin/bash
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
awk -F: 'substr($1, length($1)) % 2 && substr($5, 1, 1) ~ /[AEIOU]/' file
```

It splits each line into fields on each `:` and prints lines where the last character of the first field is odd (we assume that it is always a number) and the first character of the fifth field is an uppercase vowel.

Comment: Can you explain me why `%2` at `substr($1, length($1)) % 2` ? Thanks

Comment: It's a modulo operator which returns the remainder of dividing the number by 2. If it's an odd number, the result will be 1 which is true.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following `awk` command since it allows you to express the problem in a pretty clean way:

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /[13579]$/ && $5 ~ /^[aeiou]/i' file
```

Using `:` as the delimiter the username can be accessed in field 1 and the name in field 5.

The regexes checks whether the name starts with a vowel `^[aeiou]` and the username ends with an odd digit `[13579]$`. The option `i` makes the regex case insensitive.

Comment: Because there is no line in input with both username ends with even digit and name starts with a vowel ;)

Comment: Oh you said *odd*. missed that. Changed the answer.